# How to copy contacts from Data Extension to Publication List manually?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, publicationlist

I have a Data extension with emails and would like to use publications list with it. I tried creating a Safehouse in FTP and do transfer file activity, but it just doesn't work - saying I don't have a file in the folder and not letting my choose the right destination (move file rom export to Safehouse). Am I missing a step?

Here is what I am trying to do based on answers to similar question:

1. Export DE to FTP (done)
2. Move DE file to Safehouse folder (no export folder appears in file transfer activity, cannot complete the step)
3. Create Import activity to add contacts to publication list (cannot complete, no file found in FTP with my DE)

I'd appreciate more detailed answer - step-by-step on how to import contacts to publication list manually.

Comment: Why do you want to automate this process? It’s enough if you choose your publication list upon the email send, anyone who is not on it will be added there automatically.

Comment: *they will be added with “Active” status